# RESTful Services - Avoid stacktrace to client

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, cxf

I am developing a restful webservices using java. I am handling all runtime and other possible exception scenarios to send meaningful response to client.

When something like out of memory occurs, how do i make sure client gets meaningful response from the server?

Am using CXF and ExceptionMapper.

Comment: Use a filter for your URLs where you will handle the exception thrown. Apart of that, I would worry more on why there's an OOM in the app.

Comment: I gave OOM as an example, can you please elaborate more.

Comment: catch Throwable and return an error code.

Comment: did you gone through http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc?

Comment: I can handle all Runtime and Checked exceptions using ExceptionHandler or ExceptionMapper. But the problem is how do i do with errors?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring, you can catch your exceptions and map them to meaningful HTTP status codes. Following code might work for you (maps `YourException` to HTTP 500):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionProcessor {

  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
  @ExceptionHandler({YourException.class})
  public void serverError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
    // ...
    // Print exception to server log
    exception.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: I can handle all Runtime and Checked exceptions using ExceptionHandler or ExceptionMapper. But the problem is how do i do with errors?

Comment: Do you mean sending a message back to caller along with status code ? Try [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exception; it's an error: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

You can catch it as it descends from `Throwable`:

```
try {
    // create lots of objects here and stash them somewhere
} catch (OutOfMemoryError E) {
    // release some (all) of the above objects
}
```

However, unless you're doing some rather specific stuff (allocating tons of things within a specific code section, for example) you likely won't be able to catch it as you won't know where it's going to be thrown from.

If the root cause of your problem is a memory leak, then the chances are that catching and recovering from the OOM will not reclaim the leaked memory. You application will keep going for a bit then OOM again, and again, and again at ever reducing intervals.

**There is probably at least one good time to catch an `OutOfMemoryError`, when you are specifically allocating something that might be way too big:**

Comment: The problem is not about how to catch it, but **where**.

Comment: I dont want to catch throwable. I am looking for a way using JAX-RS api.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `OutOfMemoryError` is that it may happen in *any thread*, including threads that do not run your REST services code. In a server context, it is considered a bad practice to catch any `Error`. You should let it bubble up the call stack to be handled by the server code.

Instead of catching it, it would be better to investigate why you run out of memory and fix the cause. It could be that your server simply doesn't have enough memory allocated, or that you have a memory leak somewhere. You need to analyze the problem, for instance by analyzing the resulting heap dump(s), and ensure that it doesn't happen anymore.

In a managed environemnt like a Java EE server, it is dangerous and generally fallacious to assume you can recover from OutOfMemeoryError by catching it. Most often, you can't even catch it because it happens in a thread you don't control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using HandlerExceptionResolver for this:

```
public class MyHandlerExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
          Your error processing goes here
    }
}
```

So every exception, goes in resolveException, and I write appropriate message (In my case JSON) to the response.

There is also a good article http://www.journaldev.com/2651/spring-mvc-exception-handling-exceptionhandler-controlleradvice-handlerexceptionresolver-json-response-example

Comment: I am already handling all exceptions and i dont know how to handle errors.